# How To Store Column Mean As a Variable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, variable-assignment

**ISSUE**

I am performing data cleansing. I have calculated a column mean based on conditions fed into the `.loc()` function.  Storing this output in the z variable is producing a (1,1) dataframe and throwing an incompatibility error when I try to assign it to a missing value.

**WHAT'S BEEN TRIED**

*Input*

```
a = train[['LotFrontage', 'MSSubClass', 'MSZoning', 'Street', 
           'LotShape']]

z = train.loc[((train.MSSubClass == 190) & 
             (train.MSZoning == 'RL') & 
             (train.LotShape == 'IR1'))]
             .agg({'LotFrontage': ['mean']})

a.LotFrontage[335] = z
```

*Output*

`ValueError: Incompatible indexer with DataFrame`

**QUESTIONS**

1. Is it possible to store the `.mean()` output as an integer in z to fix this issue?
2. If above is not possible, is there a different method I should be using to replace the missing `LotFrontage` value with the calculated mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly... this may work.

```
z = (train.loc[train.MSSubClass.eq(190) 
               & train.MSZoning.eq('RL') 
               & train.LotShape.eq('IR1'), 'LotFrontage']
          .mean()) # Returns a float.

a.loc[335, 'LotFrontage'] = z

# Or, for all nans in LotFrontage:

a.LotFrontage = a.LotFrontage.fillna(z)
```

Comment: I haven't seen `.eq()` used before. Looks pretty useful I'll to read more into it. I also completely glossed over being able to call conditions and the column in `.loc()`. Simplified a lot.

Comment: Ye, `eq(), lt() gt(), ne(), ge()` etc. are all useful, and they help reduce the clutter of `()` everywhere :')

Comment: Do you have a link or term I could search so I could research that list?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```py
z = (train.loc[((train.MSSubClass == 190) & 
               (train.MSZoning == 'RL') & 
               (train.LotShape == 'IR1'))]
     .agg({'LotFrontage': ['mean']})
     .item())  # Return first element of Series
# or
z = (train.loc[((train.MSSubClass == 190) & 
                (train.MSZoning == 'RL') & 
                (train.LotShape == 'IR1'))]
     ['LotFrontage'].mean())


# Depending on what is missing value in `LotFrontage` column
# if it is empty string, you can use `.eq('')`
# if it is NaN value, you can use `.isna()`
m = a['LotFrontage'].isna()
a.loc[m, 'LotFrontage'] = z
```

Comment: Happy 20k ;) +1

Comment: I see, so using `.agg()` will return a series. Thanks for the two options.